# How do control a second parent with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists

I have a couple nested lists in one page I want to access the second ul which is not nested as well as the third. I do want to control each list on its own .
They do not have classes or Id's assigned to them (they're in a dynamic system). I need to control that with JavaScript or jquery. Can I get help on that?

Here is my code:

```
<ul class="category-list">
    <li class=""><a href="http://example.com/blackberry/">Blackberry</a>
        <ul>
            <li class=""><a href="/carrier/">Carrier</a>
                <ul>
                    <li class=""><a href="/blackberry/at-t/">AT&amp;T</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="/blackberry/sprint/">Sprint</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="/blackberry/t-mobile/">T-Mobile</a></li>
                    <li class="LastChild"><a href="/blackberry/verizon/">Verizon</a></li>
                </ul></li>
            <li class="LastChild"><a href="/blackberry/color/">Color</a>
                <ul>
                    <li class=""><a href="/blackberry/black/">Black</a></li>
                    <li class="LastChild"><a href="/blackberry/white/">White</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class=""><a href="http://example.com/casio/">Casio</a>
        <ul>
            <li class=""><a href="/casio/carrier/">Carrier</a>
                <ul>
                    <li class=""><a href="/casio/at-t/">AT&amp;T</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="/casio/sprint/">Sprint</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="/casio/t-mobile/">T-Mobile</a></li>
                    <li class="LastChild"><a href="/casio/verizon/">Verizon</a></li>
                </ul></li>
            <li class="LastChild"><a href="/casio/color/">Color</a>
                <ul>
                    <li class=""><a href="/casio/black/">Black</a></li>
                    <li class="LastChild"><a href="/casio/white/">White</a></li>
                </ul></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Do you have a <ul> nested within an <li>?  I'm confused why the first closing </ul> tag comes prior to a closing </li> tag.

Comment: I did not copy the code correctly

Comment: And I am intimidated by people who know better than me... (i've has experienced sarcasm here too)

Comment: can you give a case what you want to do

Comment: The second level can be accessed with `$('.category-list > li > ul')` and third level `$('.category-list > li > ul > li > ul')`

Comment: @ArunPJohny just show its the first level and if clicked show the whole nested list.

Comment: @csh try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ZVYmd/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny I have tried them. The problem is I do want them to link to webpages on my website, with this code added the don't

Comment: you mean when you click on a link it has to take you to that page and expand the menu properly

Comment: @ArunPJohny Yes exactly

Comment: @ArunPJohny Have any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

With the little bit of information given, I think this would work.

```
// generate a list of ul objects
var ul_objs = document.getElementsByTagName("ul");

// select your desired ul
var desired_ul = ul_objs[1];

// get a list of the children li if necessary
var desired_ul_children = desired_ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
```

Take a look at this [DOM Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/dom_methods.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/).

Here possibly you can use

- [parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)
- [children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/)
- [eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Answer (score 0):

If you apply it to the next nevel children and all children at once you can do this:

```
$(this).children('ul').anyfunctionyouwanttodohere()
```

If you need to treat individually you can do this:

```
 $(this).children('ul').each(function(){
  // do the something for each ul accordingly
 });
```